# Cannot read property 'getContent' of undefined in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I am working to send mail using rich text from Tinymce editor and displaying but I am getting following error while debugging in javascript
**Cannot read property 'getContent' of undefined**

Here is my code
//Model

```
 public class EmailModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public string Receiver { get; set; }
        public string SubjectText { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        [UIHint("tinymce_full_compressed")]
        [Display(Name = "BodyText")]
        public string BodyText { get; set; }
        public string AboutMe { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmailListModel
    {

        public List<EmailModel> ListEmailModel { get; set; }
        public EmailModel EmailModel { get; set; }
    }
```

//View

```
@model StarRatingControl.Models.EmailListModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeMail";
}

<h2>EmployeeMail</h2>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>About</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailModel.SubjectText, new { @class = "col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailModel.SubjectText, new { @style = "width:790px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailModel.SubjectText)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailModel.BodyText, new { @class = "col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailModel.BodyText)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailModel.BodyText)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" id="sendMail" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//JS

```
$("#sendMail").click(function () {
        $('#' + 'BodyText').html(tinymce.get('BodyText').getContent());
        var subject = $("#SubjectText").val();
        var body = $("#BodyText").val();
        var data = {
            subject: subject,
            body: body
        };
        alert(body);
        $.post('@Url.Action("SendEmpMail", "ManageEmployee")', data, function (res) {
            if (res)
            {
                alert('Mail Sent Successfully');
            }
        });
    });
```

**One important point is when I was using EmailModel in view everything was working fine but due to displaying I used EmailListModel.** After using this model I am not getting values.

Comment: I do not see the point of using EmailListModel. If you want to use LIST of the model in the view you can Use `@model IEnummerable<EmailModel>`.

Comment: But I want to post data from same page also. So how will I do if I use `@model IEnummerable<EmailModel>`

Answer (score 0):

The `tinymce.get()` command requires you to pass the ID of the `<textarea>` that TinyMCE replaced.   If you are seeing...

```
Cannot read property 'getContent' of undefined
```

...then your `tinymce.get()` command is not correct.  So the question becomes what does this code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailModel.BodyText)
```

create in the browser?  What is the ID of the underlying `<textarea>`?  Once you know that you can use your `get()` command to target that editor instance.